# MySql.EntityFramework a suitable constructor could not be located

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

It's the first time i'm trying to use an EntityFramework for doing operations on DB.

My DB is set in MySQL so i've installed all needed NuGets packages for it and i was trying to set the `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` but when i try to run the program i get the following error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
> constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> 'ServiceType: VisualPos.Data.MyDbContext Lifetime: Scoped
> ImplementationType: VisualPos.Data.MyDbContext': A suitable
> constructor for type 'VisualPos.Data.MyDbContext' could not be
> located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for
> all parameters of a public constructor.)'

My code looks like this:

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VisualPos.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build(); // CODE CRASH HERE

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

MyDbContext.cs

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using VisualPos.Models;

```
namespace VisualPos.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        
        public DbSet<Cfg> Cfg { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
    }
}
```

Then in my controller i would just do `_context.Cfg.ToList();` where `_context` is `MyDbContext` context.

The cfg table yet exists in DB.

Comment: What NuGet packages (for MySQL and EF Core) and versions are you using?

Comment: @BradleyGrainger MySql.Data 8.0.27, MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0-preview3.1 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the error message:

> A suitable constructor for type 'VisualPos.Data.MyDbContext' could not
> be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered
> for all parameters of a **public constructor**.

Your constructor is `protected`. It should be:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
```